# ssrs report does not show range stock graph in preview

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

Hi I'm working on my ssrs range stock with line graph. The graph was worked properly. But now the graph display all data except the stock line.

I deployed the current graph, it working properly. Web shows the stock line. I restarted the report server. but it not working. Plz give me a suggestion. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try to remove the cached data files: http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2011/08/how-to-delete-cached-data-in-sql-server.html

Comment: i tried, but the result is same